# Stop Paypal recurring payment in Paypal Standard

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am using paypal recurring payment for my site when user select a checkbox for recurring paymet, but if after some time if user want to remove recurring payment and need regular payment option then we are thinking to provide facility to uncheck checkbox..

At that time its directly **unsubscribe recurring payment** from the **paypal(Using Paypal standard)** without need to visit paypal site.

please let me know how to do that. **Is there any API for unsubscribe recurring payment from our side.???**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to Page 136 of [PayPal "Name-Value Pair API Developer Guide"](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide.pdf) - it details the required variables to execute a Recurring Payment Cancellation.

Comment: Its not working with Paypal Standard.i am asking for that only..     my site working good with paymentPro already..Thanks.

Comment: If this is a cancelled question (ie there was no solution other than to upgrade your PayPal account, which seems the case here), can you please close your question? Please also close any other related questions you asked which are no longer required/active - it makes StackOverflow a nicer place to use.

Comment: Your question never stated that you needed a solution for PayPal Standard and that you would not use PayPal Pro. It seems that PayPal choose to only allow this level of interaction for Pro Account Holders. If that is the case (and I think it is) then there is no solution to your question. Please close this question if it is no longer needed, or has no solution. Thanks.